# Getting orphaned text out of parent tag with child elements serparating

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, dom, tags

I have a programming challenge, and I'm wondering what the most bug-free way to approach it is.

Basically, I have the following HMTL:

```
<p id="first">
    Hello lorem ispum 
    <a id="link" href="...">Link</a> 
    linkety link blag
</p>
```

(the id's are for proof of concept in getting by getElementById: in reality, I get the DOM references element-by-element parsing the page).

The "Hello lorem ispum" and "linkety link blag" text fragments are orphaned -- I cannot directly access them. I can only access the whole thing with the paragraph tag, or the inside "a" tag.

What I would like is an array of elements of the stuff in the paragraph.
If they need to get wrapping  tags or something in order to get a reference to modify with JavaScript, that's OK.
E.G., end result:

```
para[0] = <span>Hello lorem ispum</span>
para[1] = <a id="link" href="...">Link</a>
para[2] = <span>linkety link blag</span>
```

DOM Objects that I can change/access linking to what's on the page (NOT strings).

Would it just be a bunch of parsing the paragraph tag's innerHTML?

This is all for an open source Chrome plugin for disabilities in reading text by simply using up and down arrow keys. If you have any better ideas of how to approach this problem, please let me know!

Comment: so you need the values of the text nodes in an array? something like ["hello lorem ispum","linkety link blag"] ?

Comment: You could use the element's [childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.childNodes)

Comment: That's a good starting point... Thanks for the tip, Musa.

Comment: All answers submitted were very helpful. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the `childNodes`

```
   var para = document.getElementById('first');

var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < para.childNodes.length; i++) {
    var elem = para.childNodes[i];
    if (elem.nodeType === 3) {
        var newElem = document.createElement('span');
        newElem.className = 'a';
        newElem.innerHTML = trim(elem.nodeValue);
        elem.parentNode.insertBefore(newElem, elem.nextSibling);
        para.removeChild(elem);
        arr.push(newElem);
    }
    else {
        arr.push(elem)
    }

}
console.log(arr);

function trim(str) {
    return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
}​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/RkcUk/2/)**

Comment: This is very close to what I'm looking for, but I get ["<span>[object Text]</span>", 
<a id=​"link" href=​"http:​/​/​google.com">​Link​</a>​
, "<span>[object Text]</span>"]

Comment: (works now, but... ) Hmm, I don't want them to be strings though -- I want the actual HTML on the page with the orphaned text to get the <span> tags, and then get the references to the span tags into an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
var paragraph = document.getElementById('first'),
    list = paragraph.childNodes,
    l = list.length,
    el, container, i = 0, result = [];

for(i; i < l; i++) {
    el = list[i];
    if (el.nodeType === 3) {
        container = document.createElement('span');
        container.className = 'wrapper';
        // we want to remove line breaks from the text
        container.innerText = el.nodeValue.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
        el = container;
    }
    result.push(el);
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/rXZMW/5/)

The reason we want to remove line breaks from the text nodes is that those will be converted into `<br>` when in a `<span>`. Don't think this is what you need.

In your particular case, `result` will be something like:

> [SPAN, LINK, SPAN]

Comment: Thanks, but I need the actual <span> references (where the actual HTML changes to give the orphaned text the span tags to reference)

Comment: @aeharding, I have updated the code snippet and the fiddle for your usecase.

Comment: You're welcome @aeharding. I think you should do some acceptance for the answers. Or at least up-voting for the answers that you find useful. It will improve your "stackoverflow karma" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it creates a span with content of the text node and replace it with the text node

```
var p = document.getElementById('first');    
var elements = [];    
for (var i = 0; i < p.childNodes.length; i++) {
    var child = p.childNodes[i];
    if (child.nodeType == 3) {//text node
        if (! /^\s+$/.test(child.nodeValue)){//skip whitespaces
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.innerHTML = child.nodeValue;
            p.replaceChild(span, child);
            elements.push(span);
        }
    }
    else if (child.nodeType == 1){//element node
        elements.push(child)
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/t6UaJ/

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the text from the text nodes that aren't in other elements like this by walking the child nodes of the `<p>` tag and looking at the nodeType to see which nodes are text nodes:

```
var top = document.getElementById("first");
var node = top.firstChild;
while (node) {
    // get text from text nodes that aren't contained in elements
    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        // node.nodeValue is the text in the text node
    } else if (node.nodeType === 1) {
        // node is an element here so you can get innerHTML or textContent or whatever you want
    }
    node = node.nextSibling;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/YvBpw/

---

If you just want the plain text from the whole `<p>` tag (including all elements) and do it cross browser, you can use this:

```
var t = document.getElementById("first");
var text = t.textContent || t.innerText;
```

This will be an HTML-stripped text conversion of everything in the `<p>` tag.

Comment: This is getting to what I need, thanks! Great skeleton... I'll see if I can get what I mean to work and get back.